# How to catch Windows Update events?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wuapi

I have found a lot of guides how to work and use WUAPI in order to download and install updates using my own program. But I always wanted to know - is there a way to use default Windows Update application?

For example, I launched installation of Important and Non-important updates via default Windows Update application, and upon their installation I want to catch event and show some sort of Messagebox, for example with number of Important and Non-important updates. Is there a way to implement that?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if you can if you don't have access to [System Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/system-center-2012-r2/Overview.aspx)

Comment: I think you'd have to parse the log file - but be warned that this is changing in Windows 10.